# Getting maximum value from table using group by function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2D3l.png)
Some how I am not able to succeed on executing the line below:

Could anyone help me in checking the error:

## extracting maximum Avail Ener landings per Airport

```
    df1=df.loc[df.reset_index().groupby(['Airport'])['Avail Emer Landings'].idxmax()]
    print(df1)
```

Total code here:

from random import randint
import pandas as pd
class City:
def **init**(self, X, Y):
self.X=X
self.Y=Y

```
def Avial_Emer_Landings(self):
    df= pd.DataFrame(columns=['Airport','Airline','Avail Emer Landings'])
    for i in range(0, len(self.X)):
        for j in range(0, len(self.Y)):
            a= randint(0,5)
            tmp_dict = {'Airport' : self.X[i] , 'Airline' : self.Y[j],'Avail Emer Landings' : a}
            df = df.append(tmp_dict,ignore_index=True)
    print(df)
    
    # extarcting maximum Avail Ener landings per Airport
    
    df1=df.loc[df.reset_index().groupby(['Airport'])['Avail Emer Landings'].idxmax()]
    print(df1)
```

Airport = ['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5']
Airline = ['Indigo','AirFrance','AirIndia','Lufhtansa','British Airways']

b=City(Airport,Airline)
b.Avial_Emer_Landings()

Comment: Could you please share one same df and expected output

Comment: please click on desired output link from problem description ..

Comment: Sharing data as picture is not recommended, paste dataframe in code please.

Answer (score 0):

This should return the rows with the max values.

```
df.groupby(['Airport'])['Emer Landings'].max()
```

Answer (score 0):

You start by collecting the max values as @Arundeep Chohan suggested:

```py
max_vals = df.groupby('Airport')['Emer Landings'].max()
```

Then to get your desired output, for each group you need to find the row with your desired max:

```py
df.groupby('Airport').apply(
  lambda rows: rows[rows['Emer Landings'] == max_vals[rows.name]]
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

If you have ties in certain groups (more than one Airline with the max landings value), this code will include all of them in the result but you could also do extra processing to end up with just a single one. For example you could just add `.iloc[0]` to `rows[rows['Key'] == max_vals[rows.name]]` as in:

```py
df.groupby('Airport').apply(
  lambda rows: rows[rows['Emer Landings'] == max_vals[rows.name]].iloc[0]
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Alternative method:**
You can also do this without a second group-by:

```py
df[df['Emer Landings'] == max_vals[df['Airport']].reset_index(drop=True)]
```

But this doesn't filter duplicates so you can remove these like this:

```py
result.groupby('Airport').first().reset_index()
```